# How to resolve packages dependencies in Go?

Tags: go

I'm relatively new to Go, and I wanted some source code that I downloaded. Though, it imports two packages which I do not have, namely these two:

```
import (
    "git.schwanenlied.me/yawning/chacha20.git"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"
)
```

It there a tool or way in Go that automatically reads the source files in a directory and downloads the packages needed? On the other hand, when I just try to use `go get` to download them, I get an error that it uses insecure protocol (due to git). Any ideas how to resolve these dependencies?

Comment: `go get ./...` should do the trick for all missing dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such a tool.
But in your case you may use 'go get', just remove .git from the end of the line.

```
go get git.schwanenlied.me/yawning/chacha20
```

same for import statement

```
import (
    "git.schwanenlied.me/yawning/chacha20"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"
)
```

Comment: I tried it, it didn't show any error message, but I didn't get any message that it downloaded too. Plus also need the other package too.

Comment: It shouldn't show any message that it downloaded the required package. Check your $GOPATH/src, downloaded package should be there.

Comment: There is go dep, which does a lot of that – https://github.com/golang/dep

Comment: @n-canter Okay, yes, it was there. What about the second crypto/sha3 dependency?

Comment: go get golang.org/x/crypto/sha3

Comment: @fhe mentioned go dep, not official tool yet, but looks promising

Comment: @n-canter Thank you.

Comment: Note that once the import statements are correct, `go get ./...` from the project root folder will download all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried godep? You can read the documentation [here](https://github.com/tools/godep)